# Change admin dashboard in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, orchardcms, dashboard

I want to change Orchard admin dashboard but I could not to do that. I've added this code in a .CS file

```
public class AdminOverride : IThemeSelector
{
    public ThemeSelectorResult GetTheme(RequestContext context)
    {
        if (AdminFilter.IsApplied(context))
        {
            return new ThemeSelectorResult { Priority = 111, ThemeName
= "NewAdminTheme" };
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and I have added this line to Theme.txt

BaseTheme: TheAdmin

but nothing works for me
I'm beginner in Orchard and unfortunately I could not find a tutorial that helps me.
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need your admin theme to also be a project so it , so when you create your theme using the orchard command line you want to use something like the below:

```
codegen theme NewAdminTheme /BasedOn:TheAdmin /CreateProject:true /IncludeInSolution:true
```

You can then **Activate** the theme in the Themes section of your site (do not set it as the current theme as it basically activates itself only on admin pages).

You can get more details on generating themes here https://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Customizing-the-default-theme/#generating-the-theme-structure